# Correct expression of the coefficient for negative binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, negative-binomial-distribution

I came across 2 sightly different expressions of the coefficient for negative binomial distribution:

1. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), it expressed it as in $(k + r - 1)$ trials where $r$ denotes number of failures, **choose $k$ number of successes**, that is $$\binom{k + r - 1}{k}$$
2. From the book *Statistical Inference* (Casella & Berger), it expressed it as in $(r + y - 1)$ trials where $r$ denotes number of successes, **choose $y$ number of failures**, that is $$\binom{r + y - 1}{y}$$

Could you please explain (step by step) whether both expressions above are equivalent?

Comment: 1.  The first line of 1 should read "... where $r$ denotes number of failures...", per the wikipedia page.   2.  If you replace the $k$ in the top one with $y$, it looks exactly like the bottom one, with the trivial reordering of $k+r$ to $r+y$.  Why do you doubt they are the same?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, @jbowman. I edited accordingly. I didn't think they were the same because the first expression chose the number of successes while the second chose the number of failures. With your rhetorical question, it's dawn on my now that they are essentially equivalent! Thanks

Comment: No problem; it's a pity that there is no uniformity in the descriptions of a *lot*  of distributions, it confuses me sometimes too.